# Which browsers (and versions) support the Canvas.toBlob method?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I'm working on a minimalist image creation project and I need to have the ability to create images within the browser that are in-turn used on a server.  So far, the `Canvas.toDataUrl()` method has met our needs, but I just learned of the `Canvas.toBlob()` method which would be much more convenient.

It appears that the `toBlob()` method is new to the specification by a few months (I can't find any direct reference to when it was added.)

What browsers support `toBlob` and more importantly which versions of those browsers included the integration of the method?  Additionally, is support for this feature "buggy" or in development for any major browsers?

**UPDATE**

I asked this question nearly 8 year ago.  I had tabled my previous mentioned project, waiting for any updates on the status of the `canvas.toBlob()` method.  From what I can gather on the web, implementation of `toBlob()` appears to be trickling into use across some browsers.

I ask once again, how ubiquitous is the `canvas.toBlob()` method amongst browsers that have begun integrating the HTML5 canvas object and which versions of those browsers were the first to integrate this support?

Comment: FYI, I had accepted Simon Sarris's answer when right after I first asked this question.  I've added a bounty to this question because I would assume that there is now a better answer since July 2011.  b

Comment: I have re-opened this question because I had to put this project on hold for a while and considering that most modern browsers release updates practically every other week, certainly the status on this Javascript feature has to be different that it was in July of 2011.

Comment: See https://caniuse.com/#search=toBlob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been nearly 8 years since I first asked this question.  Considering that I still get a trickle-in of upvotes and this question is often at the top of Google Searches, I figured I'd give an update to the state of `Canvas.toBlob(...)` and it's implementation.

The following table:

```
                   |             | Version Support 
                   | Version     | for 'Quality'
Browser            | Implemented | Parameter 
-------------------+-------------+-----------------
Android Webview)   |          50 |          50
Chrome (Desktop)   |          50 |          50
Chrome (Mobile)    |          50 | Unsupported 
Edge (Desktop)     | Unsupported | Unsupported 
Edge (Mobile)      | Unsupported | Unsupported 
Firefox (Desktop)  |          19 |          25
Firefox (Mobile)   |           4 |          25
Internet Explorer* |          10 | Unsupported 
Opera (Desktop)    |          37 |         Yes
Opera (Mobile)     |          37 | Unsupported 
Safari (Desktop)   |          11 | Unsupported 
Safari (Mobile)    |          11 | Unsupported 
Samsung Internet   |         5.0 | Unsupported 

* Internet Explore implements "msToBlob" rather than the "toBlob" function signature.
```

(Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob)

Answer (score 36):

### As of **Feb 2016**, these browsers support `toBlob()`

- [Firefox 19](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/19)
- [Chrome 50](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67587)
- IE10 as the prefixed [`msToBlob()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771732(v=vs.85).aspx)

Note this answer was originally written in 2011. Original answer/edits below.

---

`toBlob()` is **really** new and I would not recommend using it in a consumer app unless you can explicitly ask them to use a particular browser (or else control the environment).

`toBlob()` Was added on [May 12th](http://html5.org/tools/web-apps-tracker?from=6133&to=6134) and is of limited functionality as-defined. It does not exist in the Chrome nightly, firefox nightly, nor IE9.

It is worth noting that Firefox does have a functional [mozGetAsFile](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement)

There is yet to even be any [discussion for adding it to Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=83103&q=toblob&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Feature%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone%20OS).

The discussion for [Firefox.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=648610) They have decided to wait until the spec is more clear before they attempt an implementation.

The spec for `toBlob()` is very vague with a lot of internal questions still unresolved. They aren't even sure what params to allow for typical `toBlob()` use yet.

---

**Update on April 10th, 2012**

toBlob still enjoys no support. It still does not exist on Chrome Canary (Nightly), Firefox Nightly, nor IE9.

If you want to watch for updates in Chrome star this:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67587

If you want to watch for updates in Firefox subscribe to this bug here:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=648610

*Update:* As of February 21 2016 .toBlob now works in chrome 50 (currently canary)

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification.  The nature of this project is such that I could demand a specific browser but I'd prefer to not have to limit them that much.

Comment: This was the original answer from 9 months ago.  I don't mind awarding the bounty to this one but my hope was that there was a better solution available in the mean time.  If the bounty time expires (in 40 minutes.)  Simon, will get the answer check again, and the bounty.

Comment: This is now available in FF 19 - https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/19.0/releasenotes/

Answer (score 7):

If you may need it, this js file implement toBlob function in browsers which don't support it already: https://github.com/eligrey/canvas-toBlob.js

Here the [post](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side) by the authors and [here](https://github.com/eligrey/canvas-toBlob.js/blob/master/canvas-toBlob.js) the expanded source code.

However, it looks like even this library doesn't works in all the browsers, as it

> "requires BlobBuilder support to function, which is not present in all
>   browsers"

Answer (score 7):

There is a great JavaScript implementation of the canvas.toBlob() function with also includes the native FireFox mozGetAsFile() function:

https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob

Comment: You should mention it is a Polyfill

Answer (score 1):

It's too bad that this feature is not farther along but nice to know its status(thx Simon).

In the interim, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata/5100158#5100158) provides a great workaround to achieve the network efficiency of binary uploads by eliminating the bloat of base64 encoded dataUri strings. Obviously it's only supported by the latest browsers but if you're writing an extension or ready to pickup a dependency on a bleeding edge browser, it might be a nice option.